# next.js application ReferenceError: React is not defined

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to build a ecommerce cite using next.js I've come across this error that I cant figure out the solution to below is an image of the error, I did try to import React from 'react'. but it only gave me a different error, while browsing stack overflow i saw other post that mentioned modifying my babelrc file but that didnt seem to work either, here is the code in my babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Much more context is needed to give a useful answer. Try creating a repo with the smallest amount of code possible to reproduce this issue. In the mean time:

Try wrapping the Document HTML in `<> </>`

Try `import React from 'react'`

Hopefully these shots in the dark will help you.